# Neptune: get properties key and value from the relation lookup query

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have the following query to insert two vertices and create an parent edge.
I use `g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().toList()` to search the parent for node 001.

However, I don't see any property attached to the results. How do I modify the query `g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().toList()` such that I will see `node.name=b` in the resultset?

```
# insert node 001 
g.V("001").hasLabel("mylabel").fold().coalesce(
                    unfold(),
                    addV("mylabel").property(T.id, "001").property("name", "a")
                ).iterate();

      
# insert node 002           
g.V("002").hasLabel("mylabel").fold().coalesce(
                    unfold(),
                    addV("mylabel").property(T.id, "002").property("name", "b")
                ).iterate();
     
# edge 001 ---(parent)---> 002              
g.V("001").hasLabel("mylabel").as("v").V("002").hasLabel("mylabel").coalesce(
    __.inE("created").where(outV().as("v")),
    addE("parent").from("v")).iterate()
    
    
# lookup parent from vertice 001 
g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().toList()
```

Comment: are you looking for the properties of the parent ? If yes, the you can append dedup() by .local(properties().fold())

Comment: @PrashantUpadhyay Please show complete query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In TinkerPop when you are using a remote database, such as Amazon Neptune, the only thing that is returned by default for a node/edge is a reference to the element.  If you would like to return the property values for an element you need to specifically request them using the [valueMap()](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step) or [elementMap()](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#elementmap-step) which will return the K/V pairs for all the attributes on the element.  In this case it would look like one of these options:

```
// A map of all the K/V attributes will be returned
g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().valueMap().toList()

//Same as above but will include the id and label as well
g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens).toList()

//Map of attributes/id/label as well as the in/out vertex information for an edge
g.V('001').repeat(out('parent')).emit().dedup().elementMap().toList()
```